# Rails Authentication and Authorization without guarantee of browser sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

Right now, I am using the RESTful Authentication framework for authorizations with my rails application.  This is all well and good (though from my understanding, a little dated?), but now I need to authenticate a user who might not have an http session (such as from a application (not a browser) that is hitting my rails routes).

Specifically, I now have to support an iPhone application, that hits some of my restful routes to populate itself. However, this app needs to be authenticated, and just passing in a user name and password as parameters doesn't seem very secure. Not only is it not secure, it's not very clean (I would have to change all my calls referencing the current_user (stored in session) to manually setting the current user, as hits to my app without a browser doesn't seem to have session vars (or am I wrong about this?))

Any advice? Can RESTful Authentication do this? Is their an alternative framework (such as Authlogic, or OAuth or whatever) that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) appears able to do [token-based authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb).

For security, only permit SSL connections. Redirect any non-SSL HTTP requests to the SSL version of the site. You can use the Rack middleware [rack-ssl](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl) for this.

Comment: Seems like this might work for me, I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Hrrm...I'm not getting the token-based authentication working (it might use cookies and session vars just like RESTful does...and if so...there's nothing I can do other than roll my own solution), but otherwise Devise is good so far.

Comment: I just wasn't aware of how to use tokens, but once I figured it out, it was perfect, sorry it took me this long to accept.

Answer (score 1):

[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is pretty much the de facto authorization tool for Rails apps. You shouldn't try to re-invent the wheel in this case.

It plays well with both AuthLogic and RESTful Authentication, I believe. I don't have much experience with the latter.

Comment: Er, I'm a little confused...I thought AuthLogic and RESTful Authentication were both already authorization tools... How would CanCan "play well" with them if it would be a competitor?    Does CanCan handle the case of needing to authorize without a browser?

Comment: Don't let the nomenclature of the two fool you, CanCan is designed specifically around authorization. It's not a user system. It manages the permissions on your resources. What kind of application needs to interface with your rails app? Is this going to be a web service?

Comment: An iphone app, like I say in the question. I don't care too much about actual authorization (what I already implement works for me) I just want a way for a user to log in, and stay logged in without having to worry about http session vars

Comment: Well, you can keep the session alive for any amount of time. The session data is located server side, the user just has a session-key, which you'd be able to maintain perfectly well in an iPhone app.

Comment: Good point, though logging in (and making the session in the first place) is where we are stuck: the iphone app seems to send login info as plain text, not as whatever our authentication plugin form does. We can do separate authentication for the iphone (with the plain text, but using the methods of the plugin), but that doesn't seem right...